# How do i show half of an image on the edge of the page without expanding it horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to only show a piece of this img (the laptop). The hidden part being on the outside of the page. How do i make it so it doesn't actually expand the page where you can then scroll horizontally?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Depending on how thing is built, if its in the background image then you will need to use background-position when it goes into a smaller screen resolutions.

If this is an actual  then this can be tricky because there is a few options. you can set the parent  wrapper to have overflow:hidden and use margins to tuck move the laptop to only be shown.

You can also probably use position absolute to move the image into position.

If you want this to be only a mobile thing make sure you wrap it around a media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .myclass {
  css: value;
  }
}
```

If you can share some mark up with some css we can better help you :)